# How to force a singleton pattern through inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

I have a Java program where I have classes that extend Tool. Examples are PaintTool, EraseTool, and FillTool. I plan to only use methods defined in Tool, so I don't have to worry about casting specific subclasses.

```
public abstract class Tool 
{
    Tool singletonInstance;

    public abstract void primaryAction(String arg);

    public abstract void secondaryAction(String arg);

    public static Tool getSingleton()
    {
        //???
    }
}
```

My problem is getSingleton(). What can I put in here to satisfy the constructors of the different tools (which will have arbitrary processes in them). My understanding is that you can't make static methods abstract, so it has to be implemented in Tool.

A singleton approach is wanted so the default settings of the tools are saved. If I'm misunderstanding Singletons in Java or a better structural approach would be more conventional / efficient, please let me know.

Comment: There's a reason static methods aren't inherited.  If you call `Tool.getSingleton()`, which concrete subclass implementation would you expect to get?

Comment: Sounds more like you want a factory pattern, which could be used to generate a new instance when one doesn't exist, but return the previous created one when it does (if that's what you want)

Comment: Static methods are inherited (except for interfaces just for Java to be obtuse), it's just that it is unlikely to be what you actually want. / Always avoid (mutable) singletons.

Comment: @MadProgrammer A factory implementation is definitely more along the lines of what I need, thanks!